# Is it possible to use timeline markers for driver expression?

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I want to use timeline markers for driver expression, is it possible? And is it need to be added to `bpy.app.driver_namespace` for quick driver add like **#frame**? If yes, then how?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask, what effect do you want to achieve? There'll be a bit more work, because the driver expression have to choose which marker to use.

Comment: I want to integrate the functionality with [batch render add-on](https://github.com/Roisack/batch_render). So defining end frame value for each batch only use drivers

Comment: is it possible like this, e.g: for the first marker will be **#marker** and for the next will be **#marker.001** and soon.

This behavior consistent in blender, right?

Comment: It is possible. That way, the end marker for each render batch will be the start marker for the next one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to use marker for rendering frame ranges, but not through driver, which is normally used to trigger *value change* based on `Scene.frame_current`. What you need instead, is *property manipulation* based on [`TimeLineMarker.frame`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.types.TimelineMarker.html#bpy.types.TimelineMarker.frame).

The only thing you need to do is iterating over [`Scene.timeline_markers`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.timeline_markers), because manipulation of [`Scene.frame_start`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.frame_start) and [`Scene.frame_end`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.frame_end) for each render batch is already taken care of by [the addon](https://github.com/Roisack/batch_render). Get the list of frame ranges used by the addon, which is [`Scene.batch_render.frame_ranges`](https://github.com/Roisack/batch_render/blob/ff5499fe70e4da4bec777e1f66672455ce1fc0ef/batch_render.py#L68), and insert positions of the pair of markers into it. It is this last step that wouldn't be made simpler by a driver.

Below's an operator for you to edit and use. It converts each pair of markers named `start` and `end` directly into frame ranges:

```
class OBJECT_OT_MarkerToFrameRanges(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "batch_render.marker_to_frame_ranges"
    bl_label = "Marker To Frame Ranges"

    def execute(self, context):
        batcher = context.scene.batch_render
        marker_list = sorted(context.scene.timeline_markers,
                             key=lambda x: x.frame)
        marker_frame_ranges = []

        for marker in marker_list:
            if marker.name == 'start':
                marker_frame_ranges.append({'start': marker.frame})
            elif marker.name == 'end':
                range_dict = marker_frame_ranges[-1] if marker_frame_ranges\
                    else {}                
                range_dict['end'] = marker.frame

        for index, range_dict in enumerate(marker_frame_ranges):
            marker_start = range_dict.get('start', 0)
            marker_end = range_dict.get('end', context.scene.frame_end)

            if index >= len(batcher.frame_ranges):
                bpy.ops.batch_render.add_new()

            batcher.frame_ranges[index].start_frame = marker_start
            batcher.frame_ranges[index].end_frame = marker_end

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

**EDIT:** To strictly answer your question: *Yes*, it is possible to use timeline marker for driver expression. The function below will return `True` only if there's a marker at the current frame:

```
def any_marker_at_frame():
    frame_current = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
    markers = bpy.context.scene.timeline_markers

    for m in markers:
        if m.frame == frame_current:
            return True
    return False

bpy.app.driver_namespace['any_marker_at_frame'] = any_marker_at_frame
```

You can then use `any_marker_at_frame()` in your scripted expression.