# Use a timeline marker in driver expression?

Tags: drivers, marker

I see a very old [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5900/is-it-possible-to-use-timeline-markers-for-driver-expression) who's answer may have changed.  I would like to use a marker (by name) in a driver function, as shown here:

[image]

The 2013 answer is "no".   Has this changed?  I cannot find anything in "rightclickselect" nor in "devtalk" and thought this would have been discussed somewhere.

Comment: i would dare to say: yes, it is possible. But unfortunately your "frame start" field is not able to accept drivers...

Comment: @MartyFouts -- see Chris's answer below (and my comment on why this was a trick question!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, it is a bit mean of me (sorry James!)...because it won't help you.

The frame start value doesn't access drivers.

But the question was: can the timeline marker be used as driver?

yes!

I used an array modifier for this with this expression in count:

```
bpy.context.scene.timeline_markers["F_100"].frame
```

and...it worked!

Proof:

[image]

move the marker, then change the timeline by 1 frame, you will see, the number of cubes will change.

[image]

Comment: Okay actually I did know that, so it was also a trick question !!!   Thanks for the info that I need for other purposes.   I am searching the DevTalk and RightClick sites for discussion on this, as a favorite of mine would be top copy Last Frame as Driver and paste over the default 250 Last Frame in physics sims.  (and give Moonboots hell!)

Comment: well...with python and reacting on pre_frame_handler you could even set the frame end value by your marker... ;)

Comment: Good point and BTW I'm typing into RightClick now.  I can paste as Driver into a Cloth end frame, but not PS or Fluid!